# Testing increasing features with unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

I'm wondering what the best practices are in Test Driven Development / testing using unit tests when it comes to increasing features.

E.g. I have a requirement when an object of `Class Foo` receives a `bar()` message, it should update a given field `counter` accordingly. I create a test case for this, which creates a `Foo` object and then tests the requirement.

Now what should I do if there is a new requirement, that when `Foo` receives a `bar()` message also another field, `counter2` should be updated. Should I create a new test case for this, which checks only the second requirement, or do I just update the first test case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems that your question contains the answer. From my practice, if it's a new requirement, which doesn't change previous one, then you should create a new test for it. If it's a change of requirements -- then you should modify old test, to fit these updated requirements, and do it prior to implementation.

Comment: I think you're right. The downside to it is that for the project I'm currently working on, this will about double the execution time for the test suite.

Comment: If adding new test increases test execution time significantly, then probably it's not a unit test, but an integration test, or there are problems with your tests -- they use too much real parts of the system, which could be replaced by mocks.

Comment: The problem in my case is, that there are many cases where I need to test the new requirement, not that the single tests are slow. But I think I can solve this somehow (e.g. by running only a subset of the tests after each build). Anyway thanks for your efforts!

Comment: I usually run only the tests for a given unit of code while I'm working on it, to get the fastest possible response time to my changes.  Then, when those are passing, I run all the tests once before a commit.

Answer (score 3):

I would generally add a new test case, so that the two features are kept independent in testing, and which test fails indicates which feature is wrong.